# Can't Install Bundler, no permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Im using Ubuntu 15.10. This is the code I write in the terminal

```
gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.1.0 directory.
```

Why is it trying to install it there? of course it doesn't have permissions to install it in the root directory. If I try the same command like this `sudo gem install bundler` it works. But it is not supposed to be installed as `sudo`, it gives me problems when creating a new Rails app. What should I do?

Comment: Can you post the output of `gem env`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably start by running `gem env` and look at your default environment.

You can change the default installation directory by exporting a different `GEM_HOME`:

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem/
```